# "Rule-based" background color in QGIS attribute form containers?

Tags: qgis, rule-based, attribute-form, data-defined-override

In QGIS attribute form *Drag and Drop Designer* we can choose a backgroud color for widget containers (Tabs and Group boxes):

[image]

Is it possible to have rule based background colors depending on some attribute value, i.e. some sort of [data defined override](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=data%20defined%20override#the-data-defined-override-widget)?

I thought of a Python macro too, which sets the background color when a form loads, but I was not able to figure out how to adress the required container widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the box above (*Control visibility by expression*) and setup your rules carefully, you should be able to obtain what you are looking for.

For example :
In a table with a field called *value*, with value between 1 and 5, and three rules with corresponding background color:

1. value is equal or less than 2 (green)
2. value is equal to 3 (yellow)
3. value is more or equal to 4 (red)

I create as many container (green + sign) as I need rules (three here). In each of the container, I check *Control Visibility by Expression* and setup an expression corresponding to the specific value I want in that container.

[image]

Then, if I open the form, the container with the rule matching the value will be visible :

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an exemplary expression which colours the background colour to red?

Comment: What a really surprising workaround that I would never have thought of myself! For this time it solves my issue, but allow me to critizise that this approach might be very time consuming with the very extensive and nested forms that I have, in case of adding values/colors. If I find a pythonic solution I'll let you know!

Comment: Indeed, for only a few and simple rules, it's enough but more more complex situations, a python solution or else would be better.